# Executing one test method after another test method with their respective datasource using c#

Tags: c#

I have two test methods in my unit test framework which needs to be run exactly one after other. Both test method has different datasource i.e. MS Access DB file. In single run i want to execute both test methods with their respective database file. So, here in first test method (PaymentAdd) itself I have given the reference of second test method (PaymentVerify). But problem here is while executing the first test method it is taking the DB file1 which is accepted but while running the second method also it is referring the DB file1 only whereas it is accepted to refer the DB file2. Below is the code snippet, please suggest the solution:

```
[TestClass]
Public class anyname
{
[TestMethod][DataSource ( MS Access DB File 1)]
{
public void PaymentAdd()
{
Do something...
Do something...
PaymentVerify();
}
}
[TestMethod][DataSource( MS Access DB File 2)]
{
public void PaymentVerify()
{
 Do something...
 Do something...
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use real data source in your unit tests. Use a Mock instead.

Comment: Although feasible, its not really a unit test if one unit depends on state set by another unit. It also prevents the unit test framework running multi-threaded since you've got tests dependent on one another. It would be better to use Mock or develop your classes using an Interface pattern and use Inversion of Control to pass in test versions of the database which have the same methods that you call in your test, but which map onto trivial and non-persistent implementation methods.